# Simple Python Percentage

Tags: python, syntax, percentage

I'm trying to create a program to calculate the percentage of males and females in a class given the number of males and females in the class.

Here is what I have:

```
# Calculate percentage of males and females in a class 
males = input("Enter the number of males in the class: ")
females = input("Enter the number of females in the class: ")
total = int(males + females)
mperc = males*100 / total
fperc = females*100 / total
print ("The class is" mperc, "percent male and" fperc, "percent female")
```

Validation is telling me incorrect syntax on 'mperc' (in the print line).
I'm new to Pyton and not sure how to fix this. Any help would be great!

Answer (score 2):

`mperc = males*100 / total` fails because you are dividing a string by an int.

You best convert your input (which are strings) to `int` immediately:

```
males = int(input("Enter the number of males in the class: "))
females ... # dito
```

Otherwise, `total = int(males + females)` will concatenate strings and only convert the result of the concatenation into an `int`.

If you are using Python2, you might want to use floats instead in order to integer division:

```
males = float(input("Enter the number of males in the class: "))
```

Answer (score 1):

The syntax issue in the line

```
print ("The class is" mperc, "percent male and" fperc, "percent female")
```

is because you place side by side strings and variables. You need to separate them with commas or otherwise join them as strings.

```
print("The class is", mperc, "percent male and", fperc, "percent female")
```

should do.

The comments by schwobaseggl still apply nonetheless.